# the value is different inside and outside the for-loop C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, max, min

I am a beginner in C++, and I want to write a program that replaces the max value with the min value in an array and vice versa.

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){

    int num, arr[200],max,min,max_pos,min_pos;

    cout <<"enter array size: ";
    cin >> num;

    for (int i=0; i<num; i++){
        cout<<"Enter a value in array position "<<i<<" : ";
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    for(int i=1, max=arr[0], min=arr[0]; i<num; i++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i-1] && arr[i]>max){
            max = arr[i];
            max_pos = i;
        }

        if(arr[i]<arr[i-1] && arr[i]<min){
            min = arr[i];
            min_pos = i;
        }
    
    cout<<"max_in "<<max<<"||"<<"min_in "<<min<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"max_out "<<max<<"||"<<"min_out "<<min<<endl;



    // arr[min_pos] = max;
    // arr[max_pos] = min;
    // cout<<"max: "<<arr[min_pos]<<" || min: "<<arr[max_pos];

    // cout<<"array is ";
    // for(int i =0; i<num;i++){
    //     cout<<arr[i];}
    }
```

this is the output

```
enter how many number you want inside :4
Enter a value in array position 0 : 2
Enter a value in array position 1 : 1
Enter a value in array position 2 : 4
Enter a value in array position 3 : 6
max_in 2||min_in1
max_in 4||min_in1
max_in 6||min_in1
max 561||min -1343285512
```

I don't know why the values change outside the loop, where is the mistake?

Comment: Ask yourself: What are the starting values of `min` and `max`.  will those values be values that are in the array?

Comment: @NathanOliver check the `for` loop initialisation

Comment: @Mahmoud -- Take a look at Vlad's answer below where `std::minmax_element` is used.  Those two lines basically replace the entire code you have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
for (int i=1, max=arr[0], min=arr[0] ;...
```

You declare 3 variables, they are called `i`,`max` and `min`. `max` and `min` shadow the variables of same name declared outside of the loop.

Do not declare the variables of same name, but use the ones you already declared:

```
int max = arr[0];
int min = arr[0];
for(int i=1; i<num; i++){
```

This is a mistake you could have avoided by reading compiler warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/aT753e4nh. Also initializing variables always, and only declare a variable when you can initialize it, would have reduced chances for this kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

In this for loop

```
for(int i=1, max=arr[0], min=arr[0]; i<num; i++){
    if(arr[i]>arr[i-1] && arr[i]>max){
        max = arr[i];
        max_pos = i;
    }

    if(arr[i]<arr[i-1] && arr[i]<min){
        min = arr[i];
        min_pos = i;
    }

cout<<"max_in "<<max<<"||"<<"min_in "<<min<<endl;
}
```

you declared local variables `max` and `min` of the block scope of the for loop

```
for(int i=1, max=arr[0], min=arr[0]; i<num; i++){
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

that hide the variables with the same name declared in the block scope of the function `main`

```
int num, arr[200],max,min,max_pos,min_pos;
                  ^^^^^^^
```

You need to remove the redundant declarations in the for loop and initialize the variables `max_pos` and `min_pos` that you forgot to initialize

```
max=arr[0]; min=arr[0];
max_pos = 0; min_pos = 0;

for(int i=1; i<num; i++){
```

Also the conditions in the if statements can be written simpler

```
    if( arr[i]>max){
        max = arr[i];
        max_pos = i;
    }
    else if( arr[i]<min){
        min = arr[i];
        min_pos = i;
    }
```

Pay attention to that there is standard algorithm `std::minmax_element` that can be used instead of the for loop.

For example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

auto p = std::minmax_element( arr, arr + num );
if ( p.first != p.second ) std::iter_swap( p.first, p.second );
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    enum { num = 10 };
    int arr[num] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto p = std::minmax_element( arr, arr + num );
    if (p.first != p.second) std::iter_swap( p.first, p.second );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0
```